# How to create Okta Custom Policy in Mulesoft API Manager?

Tags: oauth-2.0, mule, mule-component, okta

I want to create an custom policy to implement Okta OAuth in Mulesoft. Same thing has been done before in Mule, but I cannot find the source, please see this video, [5Minute-Youtube-Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXC8_p94OkI)

I want to achieve the same thing, as shown in video.

How to create the XML configuration for the following YAML?

```
 name: Custom Okta Policy Example
 description: Using external Okta to provide OAuth.
 category: Security
 standalone: true
 providedCharacteristics: [Message protection]
 requiredCharacteristics: []
 requiresConnectivity: true
 configuration:
   - propertyName: url
     name: Okta Organization URL
     description: Enter the developer portal URL
     type: string
     optional: false
     defaultValue: http://dev-7482-admin.oktapreview.com
   - propertyName: clientId
     name: Client ID
     description: Okta Application client id
     type: string
     defaultValue: 0oabdnelyuUcFe0h7
     optional: false
   - propertyName: clientSecret
     name: Client Secret
     description: Okta Application client secret
     type: string
     defaultValue: FUcZlNfYd0XmExqp1xjbxVbFpp2z81ospOz8iH
     optional: false
```

Comment: Please show some love to this question :) Even I am interest to know how it can be done. I worked on other policies but not on custom policies.

Comment: Isn't Okta Oaut just Oauth? Which you can just configure in Anypoint Platform API Manager? Don't think you need a custom policy.

Comment: How can you directly configure it in Anypoint Platform API Manager? Please explain briefly. AFAIK the OAUTH policy available in api manager can only be used for mule OAuth provider.

Answer (score 0):

For the oAuth token enforcement custom policy for a third party oAuth provider, you may create one based on the one used by Mule's oAuth provider (see [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/v/2.x/external-oauth-2.0-token-validation-policy)). Just apply the policy, see what's downloaded in the policies folder of the runtime, and base your custom policy on it. Notice that you will want to remove the client ID enforcement part, since used the client ID and secrets are generated outside Anypoint API Platform.

On the other side, if you only would like to have Okta oAuth 2.0 support, you may leverage their OpenID Connect protocol just by [configuring your organization](https://docs.mulesoft.com/access-management/configure-client-management-openid-task) and applying the corresponding [out-of-the-box policy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/v/1.x/openid-oauth-token-enforcement-policy).